# How to Fix/Override a CSS template issue

Tags: css

I have my website [here](http://dev.tasch.co.za/airportshuttle2/airport-shuttle-cape-town-book-online) and I discovered a small issue regarding its CSS.

If you hover "Existing Account Client", in Payment method section (at the bottom), it's cutting the left side of the description.

You need to input some fake info and click on "See Price" then select any vehicle.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="payment_desc" title="" data-original-title="Please enter your customer account name/number in the messages section of the booking form.">Existing Account Client</a>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Make a JS fiddle or post the code. How the hell are we supposed to know what is wrong with the CSS?

Comment: There's a link on my Post. Follow the link !!!

Comment: Oh I did not know that. Im sure somebody will open the link then switch into the browsers developer mode then fill out the required forms maybe make a user account and then inspect the elements and start guessing what could be wrong with the CSS. Totally going to happen...

Comment: You really think if I was able to give you the CSS code of that section that poses problem I would let you spend time telling me all the above ! The truth is I'm not an advanced dev in CSS, so I tried to find it out by myself but I couldn't that's why posted here to get help !!!  No need to create an account on that web site.  What you're actually asking to me, is exactly what I come here to ask you guys !!!

Comment: Alice, what I think hansTheFranz is getting at is that it would be better for you to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then, if the act of doing that doesn't point you in the right direction, come back here, and edit your question with more specific information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 'position: relative;' into this section:

```
#payment_selectors label, #payment_selectors label a{
 position: relative;
}
```

It will display whole tool tip. However I spot another problem - this tool tip window is flashing. You can try shift position of tool tip by adding left: 20px; or padding-left: 20px; or something similar.

As well please change: to fix flashing issue.

```
.custom-tooltip {
    background: none !important;
    top: -80px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks "fatycow". So where do I insert that code? what is the CSS file name that I need to edit?

Comment: Try this one:
http://dev.tasch.co.za/airportshuttle2/components/com_taxibooking/assets/css/three/three_main.css

Comment: Thanks fatycow. Solved !!